# How to access a Screen through the App class in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

So I'm building a little app for personal use that consists of a calendar in which I can schedule all my activities. I've been hacking through the code for few days now and I've already done the necessary classes and functions to manage the data. Still, there is a problem with the screens I made. I don't know how to access them through the App class to add new widgets to them. In this case, I would like to update the DateScreen everytime a new activity is scheduled...

Here is a little bit of the code that I think it will help you to understand the problem a little bit better.

Python code

```
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.bottomsheet import MDCustomBottomSheet
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass 

class ActivitySheet(StackLayout):
    pass

class DateScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        kv = Builder.load_file("layout2.kv")
        return kv

    def show_new_activity_menu(self):
        """Spreads a bottomsheet to enable the user to schedule a new activity
         with the selected time and description."""
        self.bottom_sheet_menu = MDCustomBottomSheet(screen=ActivitySheet())
        self.bottom_sheet_menu.open()

    def pass_activity_data(self, time, main, desc):
        """Takes all the data inputted by the user and passes it as arguments,
         then it dismisses the bottomsheet. This is essential to allow the
         AgendaManager to create a new Activity object."""
        m.schedule_new_activity(time, main, desc)
        self.update_screen()
        self.bottom_sheet_menu.dismiss()

    def update_screen(self):
        schedule = m.show_schedule(m.working_with)
        if schedule:
            for time in schedule:
                DateScreen().add_widget(MDLabel(text="test"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

kv. code

```
Manager:
    MainScreen:
    DateScreen:

<ActivitySheet>:
    id: custom
    orientation: "lr-tb"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "200dp"
    spacing: 0

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        pos_hint: {"top": 0}
        size_hint: (1, 0.25)

        TextInput:
            id: time
            size_hint: (0.25, 1)
            font_size: 26
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"
            text: "H"

        TextInput:
            id: main
            font_size: 24
            text: "Main"
            size_hint: (0.75, 1)
            valign: "center"

    TextInput:
        id: desc
        size_hint: (1, 0.60)
        text: ""

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: (1, 0.15)

        Button:
            text: "cancel"

        Button:
            id: day
            text: "save"
            on_release: app.pass_activity_data( root.ids.time.text, root.ids.main.text, root.ids.desc.text)
```

I would really appreciate your help or recommendations. I'm really stuck with this one.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

add the screen manager in the init function of the App class.

Start by adding the screen manager to the app:

```
self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
```

So for example you have the screen 'DateScreen'. It should be in the app class like:

```
self.date_screen = DateScreen()
screen = Screen(name="DateScreen")
screen.add_widget(self.date_screen)
self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)
```

Now return the screen_manager instead of the kv file:

```
return self.screen_manager
```

About using the  from the kv file, im not sure how to import it to the screen manager. But you can find solutions easily online for that.

So basically you need to use the kv file to import the contents into the python script. Then add the screen from the kv to the screen manager. Include all the desired screens into the screen manger and then return the screen manager.